# How to retrieve Jmeter response and use on Http request

Tags: api, rest, jmeter, response, extract

Example the request I used is "https://test.com/devices/entities/devices/v1?ids=abc"

and this is my response:

{
"meta": {
"query_time": 0.003134801,
"powered_by": "device-api",
"trace_id": "Test"
},
"resources": [{
"device_id": "ABCD-1234",
"hostname": "Test-Machine1"
}]
}

My question here is how can I extract the value of device_id, hostname so I could use that on my Http request every invoke. Hoping for your response. Thank you so much.

Expected Result:
I want to retrieve the device_id, hostname and used that on my Http request every invocation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNAcT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor), the relevant [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) Expressions would be `$..hostname` and `$..device_id` correspondingly

Demo:

[image]

Comment: If I'll do that I could only extract the deviceId and deviceName on my 2nd invocation, because I'm planning to extract that value and put on my Http request. Expected Result Invoke that API and extract the value and put on my Http Request. (Dummy Sampler + hostname + hostId)